# FirebaseUI for Auth, custom layout only response to views that set to AuthMethodPickerLayout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Firebase recognizes the providers buttons in the **custom view** by setting them to **AuthMethodPickerLayout** as follows

```
//Linking the custom layout to providers
    AuthMethodPickerLayout customLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
            .Builder(R.layout.activity_auth)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.sign_in_google)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.sign_in_email)
            .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.sign_in_facebook)
            .setTwitterButtonId(R.id.sign_in_twitter)
            .build();
```

I want to make a normal sign in with user name and user password using **signInWithEmailAndPassword** method beside the other providers.

The problem is when call

```
  startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(R.style.auth_theme)
                    .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(customLayout)
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()
                            //Todo Here is the place to add more providers
                    ))
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
```

`

Firebase take control over the layout and ignores the other buttons not added to **AuthMethodPickerLayout**, So my question is there a way to Firebase recognize the others views so for e.g. button trigger onClickListener?

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: any tip on this?

Comment: Am also still facing this problem, onclick listener doesn't work on some button that is not added to the AuthMethodPickerLayout.....Also if I add it through the setEmailButtonId() method it disappears. I don't understand if this is a bug on Firebase's side